# Example of a space that is separable but not complete

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, separable-spaces

I know that in general metric space $X$ can be separable without being complete. What's a good example?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}?{}$

Comment: How do  you  know this is possible if you don't know an example?

Comment: I'm going over a test, it was a True/False question marked wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}$ equipped with the usual Euclidean metric is separable (because it has a countable dense subset: itself), but it is not complete, as we have plenty of sequences of rational numbers converging to irrational limits.

Answer (score 3):

$X= \{1/n:\ n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ with $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ is separable with $X$ countable and dense, but not complete, since $x_n=1/n$ is Cauchy, but not convergent to any element of $X$.